# Пагинация на файлах

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте, ребята.

Подайте идею как можно устроить пагинацию, но в качество БД у меня файлы, то-есть каждый пост создаётся в отдельный файл.

Answer (score 1):

очпросто.

```
$posts = scandir('./posts');
unset($posts[0]);//.
unset($posts[1]);//..
$amount = count($posts);
$perpage = 10;
$page = 0;//В норме, на нулевой
if(isset($_GET['page'])){//если задана страница
  $page = $_GET['page'];
}

for($i=$perpage*$page;$i<($perpage*$page+$perpage);$i++){//Спс, klopp
//Вывод поста.
}

//Всего страниц: ceil($posts/$perpage);
```

Кстати. Способ применим не только для файлов. =)

Comment: Нет ли тут ошибки :-) for($i=$perpage*$page;$i<$perpage;$i++)

Comment: Действительно очень просто, я думал на массивах придумать.

Comment: @klopp, вроде нет. Выведет 10 постов. Не?
Все, дошло. Ча поправлю.

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай поправьте на:

```
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
```

Comment: Ну это ясно, но тоже спасибо.